# What is the best way to track an object in a video?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to learn computer vision and more specifically open-cv in python.

I want to make a program that would track my barbell in a video and show me its path. (I know apps like this exists but I want to make it myself). I tried using the Canny edge detection and the HoughCircles functions but I seem to get everything but a good result.

I have been using this code to find the edges of my image:

```
gray = cv.cvtColor(src=img, code=cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv.blur(gray, (2,2))
canny = cv.Canny(blur, 60, 60)
```

And then this code to find the circle:

```
circles = cv.HoughCircles(canny, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=2, minDist=1000, circles=None,maxRadius=50)
```

This is the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwiEk.png)

*left = original image with detected circle // right = canny image*

Is this the right way to go or should I use another method?

Answer (score 3):

Train the YOLO model for the barbell to detect barbel object is better than anything you tried with OpenCV. You need at least 500 images. Those images can be found on the internet easily. [This tutorial](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/introduction-to-yolov4-object-detection-fcba8bb72449)  is kick start tutorial on YOLO. Let's give a try.

Comment: oddly the linked tutorial 'introduction-to-yolov4-object-detection-' returned this message.
"This account is under investigation or was found in violation of the Medium Rules."

the analytics-vidhya account normally publishes good content, guess there was a copyright/credit to original authors issue.

Comment: @CodingMatters, I just checked now. Thanks for the update. I shared an article which I followed during my time. The key Idea is using YOLO to detect the objects. We can find more the 100 articles related to YOLO. hope you understood my answer.

Comment: all good. Agree there's a lot more content now from multiple sources. Definately an area I want/need to spend more time on.

Answer (score 1):

If you tweak the parameters of HoughCircles it may recognize the barbell [EDIT: but with more preprocessing, gamma correction, blurring etc., so better not], however OpenCV has many algorithms for such object tracking - only a region from the image has to be specified first (if that's OK).

In your case the object is always visible and is not changing much, so I guess many of the available algorithms would work fine.

OpenCV has a built-in function for selection:

initBB = cv2.selectROI("Frame", frame, fromCenter=False, showCrosshair=True)

See this tutorial for tracking: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/30/opencv-object-tracking/

The summary from the author suggestion is:

> CSRT Tracker: Discriminative Correlation Filter (with Channel and Spatial Reliability). Tends to be more accurate than KCF but slightly slower. (minimum OpenCV 3.4.2)
>
> Use CSRT when you need higher object tracking accuracy and can tolerate slower FPS throughput

I guess accuracy is what you want, if it is for offline usage.

Can you share a sample video?

Comment: Looking at the demo, I think it could work. I’ll look deeper into that tomorrow

Comment: Not me in the video but this would be the kind of footage I want to work with. Static side view (https://youtu.be/8MVgcCkidd0)

Comment: BTW, with color disks like that green one, a simpler tracking by color is also possible:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/  
Usually with conversion to HSV color space, if it's in that video I'd also boost the contrast. Color tracking + after finding the disk, possibly findContour and compute its center.
One problem about accuracy in the new video is the parallax - the camera is close and the top of the bar appears in different angles. I don't know how that would impact the tracking box. Anyway some lowest point or center of the box have to be computed.

Comment: Also, the precise recognition could be in two passes (if these method do not provide enough accuracy) and sometimes pixel-by-pixel checking could be done, like here:

Comment: (It's not in English, but see the github link below or the code shown in the screencast): https://artificial-mind.blogspot.com/2020/09/vfx-dream-summer-rain-python-tutorial.html
Or by applying numpy mask and within the colored disk region and search for gray pixels. Then findContour and find their center and/or the lowest point (for the last video).

Answer (score 0):

What's your problem exactly? Why do you track the barbell? Do you need semantic segmentation or normal detection? These are important questions. Canny is a very basic approach It' needs a very stable background to use it. That's why there is deep learning to handle that kind of problem If we need to talk about deep learning you can use MaskRCNN, yolvoV4, etc. there are many available solutions out there.